# Inverse function of a polynomial $x(x-1)(x+1) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis

How to get the interval to get the inverse function of the polynomial $$x(x-1)(x+1) = f(x) $$, to show that the function is surjective.

The interval where the function is surjective is $x > 1$ and $x < -1$, how to get inverse on this interval ?

Comment: That's not a function, it's an equation. Are you sure you want the $=0$?

Comment: For $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$, can you prove that it is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty, \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$? Then, the surjectivity follows from IVT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$x= y(y-1)(y+1)=y^3-y$$

is cubic in $y$. Use Cardano’s formula to obtain the inverse function below

$$y= \sqrt[3]{\frac x2+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}4-\frac1{27}}} +\sqrt[3]{\frac x2-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}4-\frac1{27}}}
$$
with $x\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the overkill approach.

> **Theorem: (Lagrange Inversion Theorem)**
> Suppose $z$ is defined as a function of $w$ by an equation of the form $$z=f(w),$$
> where $f$ is analytic at a point $a$, and $f'(a)\ne 0$. Then we may solve for $w$ as
> $$w=a+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{q_n}{n!}(z-f(a))^n,\tag1$$
> where $$q_n=\lim_{y\to a}\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{y-a}{f(y)-f(a)}\right)^n\right].\tag 2$$

We may apply this theorem to the function $$z=f(w)=w(w+1)(w-1)=w^3-w.$$
Clearly $f$ is analytic. We can choose $a=0$ because $f'(0)=-1$. Thus
$$w=f^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{q_n}{n!}z^n,$$
with $$q_n=\lim_{y\to 0}\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(y^2-1)^n}\right].$$
Then, recall that for  we have
$$\frac{1}{(1-q)^\alpha}=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(\alpha)_k}{k!}q^k,$$
where [$(\alpha)_k=\Gamma(\alpha+k)/\Gamma(\alpha)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. Then,
$$\frac{1}{(y^2-1)^n}=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{(n)_{k/2}}{(k/2)!}[2|k]y^k,$$
where
$$[2|k]=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 2\text{ divides }k\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
= \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}.
$$
Letting $p_n(y)=1/(y^2-1)^n$, we have the Taylor series of $p_n$ is
$$p_n(y)=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{p_n^{(k)}(0)}{k!}y^k,$$
thus $$p_n^{(k)}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{(n)_{k/2}k!}{(k/2)!}[2|k].$$
And since $q_n=p_n^{(n-1)}(0)$, we have
$$q_n=(-1)^n\frac{(n)_{(n-1)/2}(n-1)!}{((n-1)/2)!}[2|n-1],$$
so that $$f^{-1}(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\frac{(n)_{(n-1)/2}(n-1)!}{n!((n-1)/2)!}[2|n-1]z^n=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\frac{(n)_{(n-1)/2}}{((n-1)/2)!}[2|n-1]z^n.$$
This result is mess, so lets clean it up. Preforming the index shift $j=n-1$, we have
$$\begin{align}
f^{-1}(z)&=\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1}\frac{(j+1)_{j/2}}{(j/2)!}[2|j]z^{j+1}\\
&=\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\frac{(2j+1)_{j}}{(j)!}[2|2j]z^{2j+1}+\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{2j+2}}{2j+2}\frac{(2j+2)_{(2j+1)/2}}{((2j+1)/2)!}[2|2j+1]z^{2j+2}\\
&=-\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{(2j+1)_{j}}{(j)!}\frac{z^{2j+1}}{2j+1},\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
where we get $(3)$ from the fact that $[2|2j]=1$ and $[2|2j+1]=0$. Then using the definition of $(x)_n$, we have
$$f^{-1}(z)=-\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\Gamma(3n+1)z^{2n+1}}{\Gamma(2n+2)\Gamma(n+1)}.$$
We are fortunate enough to express this as a [hypergeometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html). To do so, write
$$t_n=\frac{\Gamma(3n+1)z^{2n+1}}{\Gamma(2n+2)\Gamma(n+1)}.$$
Then
$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{(n+1/3)(n+2/3)}{n+3/2}\frac{27z^2/4}{n+1}, \qquad t_0=z.$$
Thus
$$f^{-1}(z)=-z\,_2F_1(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3};\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{27}{4}z^2)\qquad |z|<\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}.$$

---

Edit: In case you're interested, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a1cr58bxb2) is some numerical verification of my answer.

Comment: Wow, this is a solution. It exceeds my knowledge of mathematics, but it is very interesting to see it. We will take all the classes necessary for this in the future, now I know how the learned methods will come to good use.

Comment: @BiliDebili I'm so glad you enjoyed it, I had a lot of fun with it too. It's nothing too advanced really, just the Lagrange inversion theorem and a bit of series manipulation.

Comment: Fun little side note, if we let $F(x)=\,_2F_1(\tfrac13,\tfrac23;\tfrac32;x)$, then we have $$\int_0^1xF(x)^3dx=\frac{27}{4}\int_0^1F(x)dx-\frac{27}4$$

Comment: Notice that $$-z\,_2F_1(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3};\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{27}{4}z^2)=-\frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}
   z}{2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$x(x-1)(x+1) =x^3-x= y$$ and then th cubic equation
$$x^3-x-y=0$$ for which the discriminant $\Delta=4-27y^2$ must be negative in order to have only one real root. This defines
$$-\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}} <y <\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Using the hyperboic method for only one real root, we then have
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3} }\frac{ |y|}y   \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}
   }{2}|y|\right)\right)$$